# Stashing ConnectionString in class

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a class that initializes with a Connection String that various functions in the class use to access the SQL Database referenced.  Currently the class stashes the passed in ConnectionString in a private readonly string.

As I am writing the using statement for the hundredth time in the functions:

```
using (SqlConnection SQLCon = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
```

I am wondering if it would be better to actually stash the connection string in a private readonly SqlConnection instead of the string form?  I am guessing this would save the cost of the SqlConnection creation multiple times, at the cost of slightly more memory usage for the SqlConnection object vs string?

Would this also benefit the pooling of the connection and garbage cleanup processes running in the background?

Am I correct that this would be the better way regardless of whether there was benefits to pooling and GC??

If I did this, would it still be beneficial to have the using statement for actually utilizing the connection or would this be viewed as dumb and I should jsut .Open() and .Close() each time I want to use it?

```
using(_SqlCon)
{
   _SqlCon.Open();
   ...
}
```

Comment: SQL connections should be short lived, you could have a `private SqlConnection GetConnection()` method. The `using(.....)` is to get sure the `.Dispose()` is called regardless of errors, check the official documentation [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using)

Comment: I want the active connection to be short-lived, yes.  But can the SqlConnection object itself be stored for the life of the class?  It would be opened and closed within each function for only as long as I am accessing data, not left open.

Comment: Do you want to save the connection _string_ or the SqlConnection _object_? Your title and question text say the former, but this comment implies the latter.

Comment: That is my actual question.  "Should" I be saving the string and recreate the SqlConnection object every time I need it (which is what I am doing right now).  Or should I create a SqlConnection variable right at initialization from the passed in String and just reference the SqlConneciton variable instead of recreating the SqlConnection each time I need it.

Comment: well, it depends on how much time will the instance of the class would be used. There is nothing wrong per-se with any of the alternatives, it just depends on how you use that class.

Comment: If you use the code from your last example I'm not sure in what state that _SqlCon instance will be if you re-use it. It called its Dispose method so it should have released any (un)managed resources it hold on to and is probably now waiting for the GC to collect it. Because you still reference it GC will skip and if that code runs again re-using that instance it is either luck or coincidence if that _SqlCon will actually successfully handle that Open call. You're more likely to exhaust ports/pools by being 'clever'. Those are fun and time consuming bugs when that code hits production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a good idea to try to re-use the same connection object. For one reason, after the `using` block ends the connection is *disposed* and is not usable again. For another if forces you to run all queries in the app in serial, with limited possibility of parallel work. So then you might be tempted not to have `using` blocks at all, and [that is also a mistake](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/398790/8057).

What you can do instead is have a shortcut method to return a new connection:

```
public static class DB
{
    public static SqlConnection CreateCn()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

And then the first snippet in the question can reduce to this:

```
using var SQLCon = DB.CreateCn();
```

I might also spell out the full `Connection` in the name, since you can get completion in the IDE to keep typing fast.

But I tend to take it a step further and also make that kind of method **private**, such that all database access is forced to take place as part of this class. Then I'll build a public method here to wrap each query, so the rest of the application is calling code like `DB.SomeQuery()` and you never see SQL strings in the main application. As the app grows I may also break it out into a separate assembly, so I can have additional classes for logically grouping different areas, but still limit access to the core connection.

Comment: Ahhh, good call on the private function to shorten the using statements, yes I would keep it private since it shouldn't be needed by the calling program.  But, I tested the using command disposing the SqlConnection and it doesn't seem to have an adverse affect.  I can have multiple using agains the same SqlCommand object and they all work.  Maybe up until GC kills it off, so may not be reliable, but it does work at least in my testing.

Comment: Yep, just verified, once GC hits, the SqlConnection is unusable stashing the SqlConnection object itself.  So that answers my original question and you get bonus points for still cleaning up my code.  Thank you.